# Security vulnerability in Java application launched using JNLP

Tags: java, security, ssl, ssl-certificate, jnlp

I am trying to launch a Java application "Java-app" using a JNLP file.

**Scenarios:**

1. This Java-app communicates with an app server "X" running either on
   the same machine or a different machine, let's say this machine as
   "Machine-A".
2. Java-app connects with "X" to validate the user name and password.
3. Note that the connection between "Java-app" and "X" is encrypted using self-signed or CA certificate.

**Security vulnerability**

I am facing a security vulnerability in the below use case:

If a hacker from another machine within the same intranet, "Machine-B", which has got nothing to do with "Java-app" or server "X", tries to sniff traffic between them using a dummy X509 certificate, then the hacker can view the password shared between Java-app and "X", by posing itself as a dummy server.

**Known but not feasible fix:**

I think this issue is because there is no proper certificate validation implemented been done by Java-app while connecting to server "X". The current logic simply validate if the X509 certificate is valid. Thats all. And it will hold true for hacker certificate.
**Possible fix:** If a valid certificate is already stored in keystore of "Machine=A" then while Java-app connects with server "X", it can validate the connection based on the certificate in keystore. But due to the backward compatibility issue, this is not feasible for me.

So is there a way to perform this certificate validation while launching the Java-app using JNLP.

**Update**

I found this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/development.html
Here under "If an application is written to run in a secure sandbox, it must follow these restrictions:" it mentions "Network connections are enabled only to the host from which the JAR files are downloaded."... does this means that if network connection is available to other hosts then this security issue might come up?

Comment: Consider communicating over https

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen its already communicating over https..

Comment: Properly set up https should be what you are looking for

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/development.html

Here under "If an application is written to run in a secure sandbox, it must follow these restrictions:" it mentions "Network connections are enabled only to the host from which the JAR files are downloaded."... does this means that if network connection is available to other hosts then this security issue might come up?

Comment: "The secure sandbox" is when you have not added meta-data saying your app needs to break out of the sandbox.    Also, you are aware that Java WebStart is not supported directly in the Java runtime after Java 8?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes, I am aware of it. But sure if Oracle omitted it since the web start has security vulnerabilities with it.

Comment: The path they want us to go is to embed a minimal jre within each app and deploy with something else.  Everything outside that scenario is being moved out of the openjdk